# Combine two queries in one

Tags: mysql

I should made a report from these datas:

```
|--------|---------------|------------|----------|--------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId | BIL_Date   | BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity |
|--------|---------------|------------|----------|--------------|
| 1      | 90            | 2017-04-01 | 85.00    | 1            |
| 2      | 90            | 2017-04-02 | 85.00    | 1            |
| 3      | 90            | 2017-04-03 | 85.00    | 1            |
| 4      | 92            | 2017-04-07 | 95.00    | 1            |
| 5      | 93            | 2017-04-10 | 85.00    | 1            |
| 6      | 93            | 2017-04-11 | 85.00    | 1            |
| 7      | 93            | 2017-04-12 | 85.00    | 1            |
| 8      | 94            | 2017-04-07 | 95.00    | 1            |
| 9      | 95            | 2017-04-12 | 95.00    | 1            |
| 10     | 95            | 2017-04-13 | 95.00    | 1            |
|--------|---------------|------------|----------|--------------|
```

I need:

- Number of night per day booked.
  For example, from the datas table, I should have `2` for the `2017-04-12` and `1` for the other dates.

The working query for that:

```
SELECT BIL_Date,
COUNT(*) AS total_nights 
FROM ___BillableDatas 
WHERE BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-04-01" AND "2017-04-30" 
GROUP BY BIL_Date ASC
```

- Get the revenue for each date in the same period.

The working query for that:

```
SELECT BIL_Date,
SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) AS sumRevAccomodation
FROM `___BillableDatas` 
WHERE BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-04-01" AND "2017-04-30" 
GROUP BY BIL_Date ASC
```

---

My question:
How I can combine these two queries in one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to mix both select clauses as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_nights, BIL_Date,SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity)  AS sumRevAccomodation 
FROM ___BillableDatas 
WHERE BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-04-01" AND "2017-04-30" GROUP BY BIL_Date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_nights, SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) AS sumRevAccomodation, BIL_Date FROM ___BillableDatas WHERE BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-04-01" AND "2017-04-30" GROUP BY BIL_Date ASC
```